# Ruby regular expression to extract words in a string that contain no spaces

Tags: ruby, regex

Say I have the string `str = "ASimpleNoSpaceTitle"`. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to use regexp to split and extract all the capitalized words so that I get `["A", "Simple", "No", "Space", "Title"]`.

What's a regular expression that will do the job?

UPDATE: What about a string of words with and without spaces/upper-case? Like `"ASimpleNoSpaceTitle and a subtitle"` to `["A", "Simple", "No", "Space", "Title", "and", "a", "subtitle"]`

Comment: When I first read your title I thought you were implying that some words contain spaces! :-)

Comment: If any of the answers were helpful, please consider selecting one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using [`String#scan`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/String.html#method-i-scan) with [character class ranges](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Character+Classes) will get you what you want with a simple, easy-to-understand regex:

```
str = "ASimpleNoSpaceTitle"
str.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]*/) # => ["A", "Simple", "No", "Space", "Title"]
```

You could use the POSIX bracket expressions `[[:upper:]]` and `[[:lower:]]`, which would allow your regex to also deal with non-ASCII letters such as À or ç:

```
str = "ÀSimpleNoSpaçeTitle"
str.scan(/[A-Z][a-z]*/) # => ["Simple", "No", "Spa", "Title"]
str.scan(/[[:upper:]][[:lower:]]*/) # => ["À", "Simple", "No", "Spaçe", "Title"]
```

To allow words to begin with a lowercase letter when not preceded by another letter, you can use this varuation:

```
str = "ASimpleNoSpaceTitle and a subtitle"
str.scan(/[A-Za-z][a-z]*/) # => ["A", "Simple", "No", "Space", "Title", "and", "a", "subtitle"]
# OR
str.scan(/[[:alpha:]][[:lower:]]*/)
```

Comment: Huh, I didn't know about `String#scan` - that's really useful.

Comment: @SebastianLenartowicz There's a lot of very useful methods in the Ruby core classes and new ones get introduced all the time. Worth a scan through the list now and then.

Comment: Thanks that works. I updated the question because I was wondering about how I would do it with a string with spaces as well.

Comment: Consider replacing "...they're preceeded by something that isn't a lowercase letter..." with "...they're not preceded by a lowercase letter...", as the two are not the same for lower-case words at the beginning of a string.

Comment: Thanks, Cary, your suggested wording is much better.

Answer (score 4):

```
"ABSimpleNoSpaceTitle".split(/(?=[[:upper:]])/)
  #=> ["A", "B", "Simple", "No", "Space", "Title"]
```

`(?=[[:upper:]])` in a positive lookahead, requiring the match to be followed by a capital letter.

Comment: `(?<=[[:alpha:]])` is redundant, isn’t it?

Comment: @mudasobwa, excellent observation! Many thanks. I've done an edit. (Readers: I formerly had the regex `/(?<=[[:alpha:]])(?=[[:upper:]])/`, where `(?<=[[:alpha:]])` is a  positive lookbehind, requiring the match to be preceded by a letter.

Answer (score 2):

The correct way to do this in 2016 is:

```
"ASimpleNoSpaceTitle and a subtitle".split(/(?=\p{Lu})|\s+/)
#⇒ ["A","Simple","No","Space","Title","and","a","subtitle"]
```

Comment: I explicitly call out POSIX bracket expressions such as `[[:upper:]]` as being necessary for handling non-ASCII alphabetics, and even give an example of the difference in the result. Did I miss something?

Comment: Imo, this is the best answer so far, as it deals with the OP's "update" case in a nice, compact way.

Comment: @philomory I should’ve been blind, I beg your pardon and I have removed the deceitful sentence from my answer. Sorry for that.

Comment: @mudasobwa Not a problem at all, I just wanted to clarify. Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it.

pass this regex inside the built in [scan()](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-scan) method.

regext `/[[:upper:]](?:[[:lower:]]+)?/`

All the regex does is find an upper case letter `[[:upper:]]` that is optionally followed by a lower case letter `(?:[[:lower:]]+)?`.

scan will look for more than one occurrence of the match string/char..etc

```
irb(main):001:0> str = "ASimpleNoSpaceTitle"
=> "ASimpleNoSpaceTitle"

irb(main):050:0> str.scan(/[[:upper:]](?:[[:lower:]]+)?/)
=> ["A", "Simple", "No", "Space", "Title"]
irb(main):051:0>
```

Comment: I'm curious why you would use the `+` operator inside an optional, non-capturing group, rather than just using the `*` operator?

Comment: Just wanted to be specific about asking for  one or more of  "lower".

Comment: But if you _optionally_ ask for one or more lower (which you do, with the `?` after the group), that is _exactly_ the same as asking for zero or more, isn't it?